# Reference request: Singular curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, coherent-sheaves

I'm interested in coherent sheaves on  a singular curve.(For example, global dimension, Serre duality, Riemann-Roch's theorem for singular curves,etc....)
I find treatment of it only in Hartshorn's exercises.
Are there general treatments of singular curves? And are there good references of singular curves?

Comment: Try to look into Burban, Igor; Kreußler, Bernd Derived categories of irreducible projective curves of arithmetic genus one. Compos. Math. 142 (2006), no. 5, 1231–1262.

Comment: Serre's book: Groupes alge'briques et corps de classes, or  Algebraic Groups and Class Fields, chapter IV, is a standard reference.